# How to use tags in Amazon Web Services and Azure

Tags: amazon-web-services, azure

I am currently building a solution on Azure (though the question should relate to AWS equally) and I am using a `UniqueId` tag to locate and use objects.

For instance, we have a storage account that is used for caching applications' blobs. The storage account is created with a random name but is found and presented to the application through its `UniqueId=AppCache` tag.

At the moment I am taking the approach that as more tags become useful I'll start to add them.

Ultimately we're looking for a hands off 'ChatOps' style solution. So everything created should be automated.

Should I be looking at a structured approach to tagging (and what does that look like) or is the organic approach more sensible?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I would set up a base taxonomy to start with, you can use automation across your estate to ensure that all resources follow the taxonomy.  You have a choice between simply deleting resources that don't comply or reporting on it to a central team who are responsible for chasing down and educating the owners.

I have followed the [Best Practice](http://www.azurefieldnotes.com/2016/07/18/azure-resource-tagging-best-practices/) set out by Microsoft for both Azure and Amazon:

- **Owner** - normally this is a team distribution list although sometimes it is an individual if it is a "10% time" project.  To make sure that the e-mail address entered is valid we run a hourly scan of our estate to detect if there are new e-mail addresses in this field then send an e-mail with an activation link, failing to activate results in deletion after three days.
- **CostCenter** - the numeric cost centre, we use this to feed into the end of month reconciliation.
- **SDLCPhase** - one of `Development`, `Test`, `SIT`, `UAT`, `PerfTest`, `PreProduction`, `Production`.  We use this to define different automated behavour:

  - **Development** and **Test**: deleted overnight and at weekends to save on costs.  Teams are responsible for reprovisioning using the automation in the morning.
  - **SIT**, **UAT** and **PerfTest**: deleted when the cost center in our finance system is closed down.
  - **PreProduction**: scaled down overnight and when the cost center is closed down.
  - **Production**: we validate that all resources deployed to the production subscription have this tag, if they don't we send out e-mails extensively.
- **DropDeadDate** - for us, this is a required field for everything except Production.  We run a nightly scan and send e-mails to the owner 7 days and 1 day before the **DropDeadDate** then delete the resource after it has passed.

In terms of the automation around this I have a tendency to use [Janitor Monkey](https://github.com/Netflix/SimianArmy/wiki/Janitor-Home) and some custom bots written is Azure Functions that sit in Slack Channels and do my bidding.